# What happened between Kaoru-tan's father and Hajime-kun?

Tags: danna-wakaranai-ken

Kaoru collapsed from cigarettes and overworking, so I assume Hajime went to apologize to her father for pushing her too hard, while he can't find a proper job. I understand why Hajime would do so and why he thinks he deserves to be hit, but what would her father get angry about? I don't understand why he would even want to hit Hajime.

[image]

Comment: well as a father, you would want your daughter to have a good husband who has a proper job so she won't be having a hard time to word in order to sustain their needs.. and so Kaoru's father thinks that Hajime is not worthy of being her husband and that makes him disappointed of Hajime..

Comment: @EdselJeddRenovalles I see. I understand that every parent wants that for its child, but you would expect the father to be more forgiving since Hajime came all the way to the restaurant to apologize. Thanks for explaining though!

Comment: apologizing won't get him anything.. wouldn't it be better for Hajime to do what he is supposed to do rather than rush to Kaoru's father and apologize?

Comment: @EdselJeddRenovalles he is doing what he is supposed to though. He already found a temp job. With his resume it just isnt easy but he has been trying since ep 3. Apologizing shows that he cares for his wifu enough to face her father. But I think u are correct that her father thinks the same way u think although I personally would disagree.

Comment: it's not that he wasn't able to get a job but he wasn't able to make Kaoru happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I should post this as answer. As a father, you would want your daughter to have a good husband who has a proper job so she won't be having a hard time to word in order to sustain their needs. So Kaoru's father thinks that Hajime is not worthy of being her husband and that makes him very disappointed of Hajime.